# Why doesn't mypy understand my simple class decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, type-annotation

My problem can be explained with this simple example:

```
from typing import Any, Type

class CallMe:
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        pass

def callme_factory(c) -> Type[CallMe]:
    return CallMe

@callme_factory
class DoNotCall:
    pass

print(CallMe(1,2,3))
print(DoNotCall(1,2,3))
```

It runs and outputs two CallMe objects:

```
<__main__.CallMe object at 0x0000017E6C5EF280>
<__main__.CallMe object at 0x0000017E6C5EF280>
```

But when I run mypy for it, it raises an error:

```
test_mypy.py:15: error: Too many arguments for "DoNotCall"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

That happens even though I annotate that `callme_factory()` returns a subclass of the `CallMe` class.

My question is:

1. Why does mypy miss this?
2. How do I get it to read the code correctly?

Comment: seems like a bug in mypy, but also it seems like a bad class decorator that returns a class that is incompatible with the one you're decorating

Comment: That's crazy. Might be a bug in mypy. If you do the decorator thing manually (`class _DoNotCall: pass ; DoNotCall = callme_factory(_DoNotCall)`), then mypy understands the intention, so it clearly accepts the type of `callme_factory`.

Comment: Technically, `mypy` doesn't know that the factory returns `CallMe`; it only knows that it returns a type that is a subclass of `CallMe`.

Comment: @Anentropic It's a contrived example, but it's easy to think of reasons to do it. e.g. a `dataclass` alternative.

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3135